# Convert Pandas to mapData for JVectorMap

Tags: python, json, pandas, flask, jvectormap

I have a flask/python site that needs to return pandas columns - CountryCode ("US") and Value (192656.56) - to an html template that presents a JVectorMap

mapData must look like:

```
var gdpData = {
  "AF": 16.63,
  "AL": 11.58,
  "DZ": 158.97,
  ...
};
```

The Dataframe looks like :

[image]

If this pandas df was a json list (see - http://api.worldbank.org/v2/country/all/indicator/NY.GDP.PCAP.PP.CD?format=json&mrv=1&per_page=300), this next python code works correctly, but I can't get the properly formatted variable to return from a function - with a pandas dataframe. I've tried a dozen loop / print approaches and all bugger up the desired variable output so far.

```
mapData = "var mapData = {\n"
for item in y[1]:   
    mapData += item['country']['id'] + ": " + "{:.2f}".format(item['value']) +",\n"
mapData += "}"
print(mapData)
```

This data next gets added to a Jvector script as follows:

```
function createList(country.value, country.id,indicator.id){
    var gdpData = {
        results.gdpdata   # data to be filled in from the python and pandas df
      };

    $('#world-map-gdp').vectorMap({
    map: 'world_mill',
    series: {
    regions: [{
        values: gdpData,
        scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
        normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
    }]
    },
    onRegionTipShow: function(e, el, code){
    el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+gdpData[code]+')');
    }
});
```

}

Comment: I was able to create a json response from /ind_MapData - `code`[{"AF":1955.01},{"AL":13364.16},{"DZ":15481.79},{"AO":6452.36},{"AG":26868.13},{"AR":20610.57},{"AM":10343.18},{"AW":39454.63},{"AU":51663.37},{"AT":55454.69}] 
But I couldn\t get JVectorMap to accept this nor any variant. What dev tools did you use to determine "legal" data input parameters for mapData? You did this with your mapper solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163371/using-jquery-and-online-json-data-to-populate-jvectormaps? I'm not able to compare what JVector is seeing vs what it wants

Answer (score 0):

I was able to "cheat" and make a string work (with console errors) via a Regex script and pandas string dump.

I found a better solution using pandas' own "to_json" function as follows. It is not pulling up the GDP values to the map however - it is saying the Values are Undefined - I assume I need to tweek some small parameter:

```
def MapData():
    global conn
    import wbdata
    ind_id=1

    qry = "SELECT * FROM indicator WHERE id = '" + str(ind_id) + "' ;"

    cur = conn.cursor()
    df = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
    cur.close()

    ind_label = "GDP"
    ind_code = "NY.GDP.MKTP.CD"
    indicators = { ind_code : ind_label }

    data = wbdata.get_dataframe(indicators, country=u'all', convert_date=False, keep_levels=True).dropna()

    # Get most recent data only
    data2 = data.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='country', keep='first').set_index('country')
    # Merge data with country data from database - this removes
    rslt = pd.merge(data2, df, left_on='country', right_on="name", right_index=False, how='inner', sort=False);

    rslt.reset_index()
    rsl2 = rslt[['iso2c',ind_label]]
    rsl3 = rsl2.dropna()
    rssl = rsl3.round({ind_label:2}) 

    return (pd.DataFrame(rssl).to_json(orient='values')) # see other options for to_json - orient - like columns, records, split, etc.
```

This renders a map but the `gdpData[code]` values appear as Undefined

[image]

Note RE: Wbdata.get_dataframe ... Caution - SLOW! Why? Because this fetches 60-years (1500 lines) of data !! Most-Recent-Only per-country needs pandas' `.drop_duplicates(subset='country', keep='first')` command
This can be sped up (a lot) by using a locally cached file, or database summary - or, another great option is by asking Javascript to fetch JSON data directly from the frontend - see [Using JQuery and online JSON data to populate JVectorMaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61163371/using-jquery-and-online-json-data-to-populate-jvectormaps)

Does anyone have a solution for this?